# oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found exception

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, jdbc

I am using socket programming in java and in that i connect my program to oracle database but class not found exception creating for oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

I have set my classpath for oracle drivers to "G:\study\2nd hand cars\oracle driver\ojdbc14.jar"

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in Java Project.Add your jars inside the java build path.Your project-->configure build path--->click libraries tab-->click add jars( browse your jar ojdbc14.jar) and ok.steps for eclipse.